# How to remove duplicate definitions of a gradle private repo in build script, plugin management and repositories?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

We use a private repository which provides artifacts for gradle plugins, libraries etc. all of which are used in the gradle build process.

Defining the same repository with url, name and credentials in each section leads to a lot of duplicate code and looks really messy. Is there any way to define the repository once, then use it in each of those locations?

Currently we have the following:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven {
            url <url>
            name 'mymaven'
            credentials {
                username "myuser"
                password System.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN") : AccessToken
            }
        }
    }
}
........

allprojects {
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url <url>
                name 'mymaven'
                credentials {
                    username "myuser"
                    password System.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN") : AccessToken
                }
            }
        }
    }
    apply{
        plugin("java")
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url <url>
            name 'mymaven'
            credentials {
                username "myuser"
                password System.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN") != null ? System.getenv("ACCESS_TOKEN") : AccessToken
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've seen people store repository setup in something such as `gradle/repositories.gradle` and then use something like this in each of their sub project/module:  `apply from: "${rootProject.projectDir}/gradle/repositories.gradle"`.  I've often wondered about the use of the `gradle/` folder, but considering it is the default location for the version catalogs, it seems to work.